# r - use dplyr::group_by in combination with purrr::pmap

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, purrr, pmap

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:20),
             b = c(2:21),
             c = as.factor(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,10), rep(3,5))))
```

and I want to do the following:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(c) %>% mutate(a = lead(b))
```

but originally I have many variables to which I need to apply the `lead()` function in combination with `group_by()` on multiple variables. I'm trying the `purrr::pmap()` to achieve this:

```
df2 <- pmap(list(df[,1],df[,2],df[,3]), function(x,y,z) group_by(z) %>% lead(y))
```

Unfortunately this results in error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Comment: can you clarify what is varying? you need to change the grouping variable at the same time as the `lead()` variable? How do they correspond, and is there a pattern as to how they are named or do they need to be user-specified? I think your example needs to be expanded with some more columns

Comment: @Calum you the grouping variable `c` doesn't need to be changed. I want the `a` variable modified with `lead()` function applied on groups defined by the `c` variable. Just like in this ex. `df1 <- df %>% group_by(c) %>% mutate(a = lead(b))`

Comment: but there are many b and many corresponding a? is it important to overwrite a?

Comment: it is not necessary. I thought this can be done simply with `tidyr::nest()` maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `mutate_at` and named arguments to `funs()`, which creates new columns instead of overwriting them. Note that this does nothing to `a` but you can rename the columns after this as desired.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1:20),
  b = c(2:21),
  b2 = 3:22,
  b3 = 4:23,
  c = as.factor(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 5)))
)

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(c) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("b")), funs(lead = lead(.)))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 8
#> # Groups:   c [3]
#>        a     b    b2    b3 c     b_lead b2_lead b3_lead
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct>  <int>   <int>   <int>
#>  1     1     2     3     4 1          3       4       5
#>  2     2     3     4     5 1          4       5       6
#>  3     3     4     5     6 1          5       6       7
#>  4     4     5     6     7 1          6       7       8
#>  5     5     6     7     8 1         NA      NA      NA
#>  6     6     7     8     9 2          8       9      10
#>  7     7     8     9    10 2          9      10      11
#>  8     8     9    10    11 2         10      11      12
#>  9     9    10    11    12 2         11      12      13
#> 10    10    11    12    13 2         12      13      14
#> 11    11    12    13    14 2         13      14      15
#> 12    12    13    14    15 2         14      15      16
#> 13    13    14    15    16 2         15      16      17
#> 14    14    15    16    17 2         16      17      18
#> 15    15    16    17    18 2         NA      NA      NA
#> 16    16    17    18    19 3         18      19      20
#> 17    17    18    19    20 3         19      20      21
#> 18    18    19    20    21 3         20      21      22
#> 19    19    20    21    22 3         21      22      23
#> 20    20    21    22    23 3         NA      NA      NA
```

Created on 2018-09-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).